# One testcontainers for multiple tests

Tags: scala, scalatest, testcontainers

I'm on scala, and I have multiple test files for different classes (testsuites), each of them uses testcontainers (init from the same script).

When I launch all tests in the project, all tests failed (problem connection with database due to testContainers).

When I launch separately tests, all the tests success.

Is there a way to launch only one container for multiple test files (testsuites)? `TestContainerForAll` seems to work only for tests in the same file.

---

*Edit after @Matthias Berndt reply* :

Here libs that I'm using :

- "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8"
- "com.dimafeng" %% "testcontainers-scala-scalatest" % "0.38.1"
- "com.dimafeng" %% "testcontainers-scala-postgresql" % "0.38.1"

And here my code

```scala
trait DAOTest extends ForAllTestContainer {
  this: Suite =>

  override val container: PostgreSQLContainer = PostgreSQLContainer()
  container.container.withInitScript("extractData.sql")

  container.start()
  ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches()
  System.setProperty("jdbc.url", container.jdbcUrl)
  ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches()

}
```

Comment: This question is just sloppy. Didn't specify test framework that is used (had to infer ScalaTest from the `TestContainerForAll` class, which comes from testcontainers-scala). No code that shows what you're doing. No error messages that demonstrate the problem.
So downvoting.

Comment: updated as you suggest

Comment: Well done. However now the question is: what problem is there that nested suites don't solve?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Scalatest, it should be possible to use nested Suites. I'll use MySQL as an example here since that's what testcontainers-scala uses:

```scala
class MysqlSpec extends FlatSpec with ForAllTestContainer {

  override val container = MySQLContainer()

  override def nestedSuites = Vector(
    new SomeDatabaseTest(container)
  )
}
```

```scala
class SomeDatabaseTest(container: MySQLContainer) extends FlatSpec {
  it should "do something" in {
    // do stuff with the container
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is (in java terms) to make an abstract base class, declare a container as a static variable and extend that class in your tests. In this case container will be created only once when base class is loaded.

Comment: Downvoting because there are no static variables in Scala and because this solution won't shut down the container after running the tests.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt do you have another solution?

Comment: @DavidZaltsman, my proposed solution is to use nested suites, as I've shown in my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The Weaver test framework has [great features](https://disneystreaming.github.io/weaver-test/docs/global_resources) to share resources among the test suites (also have features to share resources among test cases). Also there is a great integration with Cats. It is working sort of like DI but for tests.

First you need to register the global resource in object extending the `GlobalResource` (you also need `LowPriorityImplicits` if you want to register resources with generics such as `Transactor[IO]`):

```scala
import cats.effect.{IO, Resource}
import com.github.denisnovac.multitest.model.DBConfig
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer
import weaver.{GlobalResource, GlobalWrite, LowPriorityImplicits}

object SharedPostgresContainer extends GlobalResource with LowPriorityImplicits {

  private val container = Resource.make(IO(new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:alpine")).map { c =>
    c.start()
    println(s"Started postgresql container ${c.getJdbcUrl}")
    c
  }) { c =>
    println(s"Closing postgresql container ${c.getJdbcUrl}")
    IO(c.stop())
  }

  override def sharedResources(global: GlobalWrite): Resource[IO, Unit] =
    for {
      c <- container

      // this service returns Transactor[IO]
      xa <- DBService 
              .make[IO]
              .run(
                DBConfig(
                  driver = c.getDriverClassName,
                  url = c.getJdbcUrl,
                  user = c.getUsername,
                  password = c.getPassword
                )
              )
      _  <- global.putR(xa)(classBasedInstance)
    } yield ()

}
```

And then you use this resource in any test suit class. If you extend the `IOSuit` trait you can make the suits with `sharedResource`. Or you can use `SimpleIOSuit` and get the resource out of `global` in each suit where you need it.

```scala
import cats.effect.{IO, Resource}
import doobie.hikari.HikariTransactor
import weaver.{GlobalRead, IOSuite, LowPriorityImplicits}

import java.time.Instant

class UserRepoSuit(global: GlobalRead) extends IOSuite with LowPriorityImplicits {

  /* This is for sharing the resource among test cases */

  override type Res = HikariTransactor[IO]

  override def sharedResource: Resource[IO, Res] =
    global.getOrFailR[HikariTransactor[IO]](None)(classBasedInstance)

  test("Test with Transactor 1") { xa =>
     expect(true)
  }

  test("Test with Transactor 2") { xa =>
     expect(true)
  }
}
```